# Selecting the values of columns in a sql subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm wanting to display the actual header_titles (a row in each of my tables) from all the tables in my database

My current query

```
select column_name, table_name from information_schema.columns 
where column_name in (
select column_name from information_schema.tables
where table_schema='site'
) and 
column_name='header_title';
```

At the moment the query returns 'header_titles' 12 times (the amount of tables in my db with the field, and obviously the table names. I'm not sure how to get the values of each of the header_titles

Answer (score 0):

A very trivial example

#### UPDATE - column values are now being printed on the screen

```
$query = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables AS tbl
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.columns AS col 
WHERE tbl.table_name = col.table_name AND column_name = 'header_title')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn), E_USER_ERROR);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
  $q = 'SELECT header_title FROM '.$row[0];
  $r = mysqli_query($conn, $q) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn), E_USER_ERROR);
  $index = 0;
  while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($r))
  {
    $index++;
    echo "Table = ".$row[0].", row = ".$index.", HEADER_TITLE = ".$data[0].PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response i'll try and have a bash with this php script, need to convert the logic to use on a nodejs server.

Comment: at the moment the script is only returning the table_names rather than the value of the columns i need